# Find all values of x where the power series $\overset{\infty}{\sum\limits_{n=1}} \frac{(-1)^n (x+2)^n}{3^n}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Alright so I've worked through the problem the following way and came to the conclusion that the series converges when $x = 0$ but I don't think this is right.

Using $a + ar + ar^2 + ...$ it would converge when $-1 < r < 1$ at $\frac{0}{1-r}$.

$a$ is the first term in our sequence(?)

$a = 0$

$r = 0 \to |0| < 1 \to 0 < 1 \to -0 > x > 0 \to \frac{0}{1-0} = 0$

therefore,

Series converges when $x = 0$.

Is this at all the right idea?

Comment: Here $r$ would be $-(x+2)/3$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Hm. I clearly am confused. In any case that would say that the series converges when $-5 < x < 1$. Is this correct?

Comment: I haven't done the calculation, but that looks plausible.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your time.

Comment: $a=\frac{(-1)(x+2)}{3}$, $r==\frac{(-1)(x+2)}{3}$  so $(x+2)/3 \in (-1,1)$

Comment: @kmitov If changed the question to $\overset{\infty}{\sum\limits_{n=0}} \frac{(-1)^n (x+2)^n}{3^n}$ would the series then only converge at $x=0$?

Comment: no. The interval of convergence will be the same. Only $a=1$, but $r=\frac{-(x+2)}{3}$ as before.

Comment: The sum will be different.

Comment: @kmitov Thank you so much for your explanations.

Comment: no. I do not want to move this discussion to chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A geometric series converges when the absolute value of the common ratio is less than 1.

If we Observe here the absolute value of the common ratio is $|\frac{(x+2)}{3}|$ and this must be $<1$,so $|\frac{(x+2)}{3}| < 1$

Solving this like $-1<\frac{(x+2)}{3}<1 $

$\implies -5 < x < 1$.

So the above series converges for $-5 < x < 1$.

Comment: Thank you. A commenter above me helped find the solution but I will mark yours as the answer since it's what I got after he helped.

Comment: @Paul? Seriously at $x=1$?You will get $\sum (-1)^n$ and you think this series has a sum?

Comment: It does not convege for x=1.